# How to insert txt file content into twig template

Tags: php, twig, opencart, opencart-3

Triyng to start opencart shop at first time

At the root of the site I have the file "file.ssi"

How to insert its contents into a twig template? (header.twig)

Why is it important that the file must be at the root and called file.ssi -- I have a script that periodically changes the contents of this file at many of my sites, and on static html sites or wordpress I print content of file.ssi into template with SSI, and how to do it on twig I don't understand

I tried write in header.twig

```
{{ bla_bla }}
```

then in catalog\controller\common\header.php

```
$data['bla_bla'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_bla_bla'), $this->config->get('config_name'), date('Y', time()));
```

then in catalog\language\ru-ru\common\header.php

```
$_['text_bla_bla']        = 'my html code 1';
```

**and this html code prints on the right place.
But when I tried to do something like this**

```
$_['text_bla_bla']        = 'my html code 1' . $bla_bla_bla = file_get_contents('/file.ssi');
echo $bla_bla_bla; . 'my html code 2';
```

**site doesn't even open**

I understand the pure php error and my modest knowledge (or rather un-knowledge) php is not enough to get in $ _ ['text_bla_bla'] a couple of pieces of html and the contents of the file between them.

In general, I need to insert something in header.twig, or to solve it somehow with php, I myself do not understand where it was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This works!
in controller

```
$data['mydata'] = file_get_contents($path);
```

in template

```
{{ mydata }}
```

Comment: Very nice super simple answer showing the proper way to do this!

Answer (score 0):

It would look like this:

Controller:

```
$text = file_get_contents($path);
    return $this->render('page.html.twig', [
        'text' => $text,
    ]);
```

Then in your twig template:

```
{{ text }}
```

Comment: in doesn't works... maybу it because I have .ssi extension on my file?

Comment: it shouldn't matter if you have an ssi extension, are you sure you're feeding it the right directory path?

Comment: for testing right decision I place file.ssi into both directories - controller's and template's (when it will works, then I place it to root and will try with right path way)

Answer (score 0):

bad syntax:

```
$_['text_bla_bla']        = 'my html code 1' . $bla_bla_bla = file_get_contents('/file.ssi');
echo $bla_bla_bla; . 'my html code 2';
```

If you need to use `sprinf` so in language file you can get this data `$this->config->get('config_name'), date('Y', time()` using `%s`  `%d`

```
 $_['text_bla_bla']        = 'my html code 1 %s %d';
```